# Clarification on REST in MVC Diagram

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

First of all i don't know if this is the best place for this type of question since its not actual code. please let me know if i should use another site.

I'm doing an MVC 4 architecture diagram for a report and since this is my first project using MVC,i was wondering could some one clarify with me is REST (HTTP POST etc) between view and controller, or controller to model since the controller is getting and setting the data? also should model drawn as in the server side and view + controller on client side?

here are few of my mock ups at the moment.
 http://postimg.org/image/ebbg2g82b/
[image: Diagram 1]

---

[image: Architectural overview of Job Tracking System]

Comment: Controller is not definitely a part of client. You can say it's actually a part of Server

Comment: thanks @Nips! see i first thought it was server but i seen other sites stating it was in client

Comment: In ASP.Net MVC the "Controller" runs in the server.  But many new JavaScript frameworks used with MVC also have a presentation controller on the client side.

Comment: Thanks @MatthewWhited, great to know these bits of information! so now that i know "Controller" runs on server side, the REST component lies between view and controller? so for instances i will have AJAX requests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- First of all ASP .NET MVC is a server side framework. Basically all the code that you write in your controllers, models and a C#(Razor) code that you write in your views executes on server.
- `REST` (Representational State Transfer) is an architectural style that describes a standard for communication between client and server. Wen you claim that your application implements `REST` principles, you claim that you support a standard for working with your application. For example if you ask anyone who familiar with SQL (no matter P-SQL or T-SQL) what term they should use to query data they will tell you `SELECT` right? You can apply the same analogy to `REST principles`: in order to query data from server `HTTP GET` should be used but another rule is `HTTP GET` should not modify any server data. Another example is creation of a new object - should be done through `HTTP POST` which should not return anything except an execution status of an action: 201 - for successful creation or a 500(or any other HTTP error status) in case of an error.

So if we return to your question:

> Could some one clarify with me is REST (HTTP POST etc) between view and controller, or controller to model since the controller is getting and setting the data?

`REST` is not applied neither between controllers and views and nor between controllers and models. `REST` architecture applied to your controllers by specifying how they should be accessed and what they should return. For example

```
public class UserController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult Users (int? id)
    {
       //if id is not null return one specific user otherwise return a list of users 
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Users (User user)
    {
       //Create a new user and return an appropriate status: 201/200 on success or an appropriate error status 
    }

    [HttpPut]
    public ActionResult Users (User user)
    {
       //Updates a user and return an appropriate status
    }

    [HttpDelete]
    public ActionResult Users (int id)
    {
       //delete a user and return an appropriate status
    }
}
```

Applying `REST` is less critical if your MVC application returns views as a response (Which is one of it's major parts) so if this a case I wouldn't be concerned so much about it. If you planing to use you application as a service that exposes API to query and manipulate data, [ASP.NET WebApi](http://www.asp.net/web-api) is a way to go and in this case I wold try to make it RESTfull.

Regarding your diagrams:

- When you use 'Server' term you talk about the code that is executed on **Server**. `ASP.NET MVC` framework, it is a server side frameworks so Controllers, Views and Models are all belong to server side. There are various **client** side MVC/MVVM frameworks such as AngularJs, Ember.js and many others, so `MVC` itself doesn't mean that it's a client side or server side.

Comment: Alex that is a brillant answer! Clearly explained and answered all my questions! Thank you so much for taking the time to explain it so well :)